# mediawiki installing R error

Tags: r, macos, homebrew, mediawiki

I am trying to get extension R to work with mediawiki but have run into a roadblock with the following error:

> REngine.php: sh: /usr/bin/R: No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to correct this issue? If I look at `mediawiki/Special:Version`, I can see R listed under extensions as version 0.14, but if I try to use `<R>1:10</R>` it throws that error.

After the comment to add a symlink below I was able to get a little further. I added the following symlink to my brew installation of R:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/bin/R /usr/bin/R
```

and this was the output:

```
REngine.php: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so, 6): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /mediWiki/common/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so, 6): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /mediWiki/common/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
In addition: Warning message:
package 'grDevices' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so, 6): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /mediWiki/common/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
In addition: Warning message:
package 'graphics' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
<!--- Start of program --->
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
<!--- End of program --->
Error: could not find function "dev.cur"
Execution halted
```

Also the code I hae on the mediawiki page is:

```
Test
<R>1:10</R>
```

Comment: You need to check where the R executable is installed on your machine. On mine, it is `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I have an alias to R in /usr/local/bin. could this path issue somehow be related to mediawiki?

Comment: From the error message, REngine.php is searching for R in `/usr/bin`. You can fix according to this information.

Comment: I am trying to add R to /usr/bin but im not sure which file to add. If i add R to /usr/bin and set the permission to allow execute it says "cannot execute binary file". If I dont set the permission to allow execute it says "permission denied".

Comment: You can either change the path in REnginge.php to the path where R actually is or you can place a symlink in /usr/bin/R (type into your command line: "ln -s /usr/local/bin/R /usr/bin/R"). You might have to type sudo before it to get the permissions.

Comment: The symlink helped me get a little further. See question for more details.